# Unable to use date command to change specific date format in Bash shell on OS X terminal

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, date

I am using the `date -d` command to change a specific date format to another.
Below is the example used

```
currDate=`Wed 12 Feb 2014`
formattedDate=`date -d"${currDate}" +%Y%m%d`
echo $formattedDate
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't use backticks (`` ` ``) unless you are assigning the result of a command to a variable, in this case you are assigning a string so you should just quote it:

```
currDate="Wed 12 Feb 2014"
formattedDate=`date -d"${currDate}" +%Y%m%d`
echo $formattedDate
```

---

I don't have access to a mac so I can't test this but according to the OSX `date` man page, this should work:

```
formattedDate=`date -jf "%a %d %b %Y" "${currDate}" +%Y%m%d`
```

Many of the utilities in OSX are based on BSD versions of same so the info you find for Linux does not always translate to OSX. From [`man date`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) on OSX:

```
 -f      Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided
         rather than using the default [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss] format.

 -j      Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag in 
         addition to the + option to convert one date format to another.
```

Comment: It is not working in this form on OSX either. One issue I notice is `-d` which according to man is an option to specify dst. It needs `-f` to specify input format but that is not working either.

Comment: @Ketan sorry, I missed the OSX tag (in the future, please include the OS info in your question as well). see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for replying ,
but the alternative you gave is not working either

Comment: @Jagdeep you'll have to tweak it to find the right format. Read the manual page, or tell me what "not working" means exactly, do you get an error? A different format? Different date? You might need to change `%d` to `%e` for example.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I just updated mine after trying this for the record.

Comment: @Ketan and that's how these sites work, don't worry about it, you found the right answer, I didn't :)

Comment: @terdon: after executing the command it shows me usage of date command , which I conclude that the date command format is not working ..

Comment: @terdon : your second example worked i.e. by giving input format of date and output format , I am able to get the result

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I tested the following on my OSX which worked:

```
currDate="Wed 12 Feb 2014"
formattedDate=`date -v"${currDate}" +%Y%m%d`
echo $formattedDate
```

From the manpage `-v` is:

> Adjust (i.e., take the current date and display the result of
>                the adjustment; not actually set the date) the second,
>                minute, hour, month day, week day, month or year according to
>                val.  If val is preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date
>                is adjusted forwards or backwards according to the remaining
>                string, otherwise the relevant part of the date is set.  The
>                date can be adjusted as many times as required using these
>                flags.  Flags are processed in the order given.

This will get the right answer:

```
date -jf"%a %e %b %Y" "Wed 12 Feb 2014" +%Y%m%d
```

The output is:

```
20140212
```

Comment: Does that correctly display `20140212`? If I read the man page correctly, it should just add to today's date unless you use `-f`. "Take the **current date**"

Comment: @terdon yeah it is not printing the desired vals. Not accepting the `-f` option either fiddling for 30 minutes now.

Comment: Should be close to what I posted dammit. The issue will be getting the input format right. You should need both `-f` and `-j`.

Comment: @terdon Absolutely! Updated my answer based on yours :-)