# How to split existing mailboxes based on date with procmail

Tags: backup, procmail

I have huge mailboxes I would like to manage based on the age of their content: backup, archival or removal.
I would like to split these mailboxes along the date of their contained messages.

For a mailbox:

```
${MAILDIR}/${TOPIC}
```

Here is the scheme of a new directory structure I would like to span it on:

```
${MAILDIR}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${TOPIC}
```

Is there a way to achieve this splitting without too many forked commands?

Answer (score 1):

First off, a couple of clarifications.  The `Date:` header is not very reliable, as the sender could set it to pretty much anything.  However, the alternatives are not very attractive, either; some mail clients actually try to parse the `Received:` headers, but because the contents of the header are not properly standardized, that can fail.  If you have your messages in Berkeley mbox format, the `From_` pseudo-header usually contains the local delivery timestamp, but I imagine there are delivery programs which omit that, too (and it seems like you are not using mbox anyway).

So, let's just look at parsing the RFC822 `Date:` header without forking.

An additional conundrum is that not all senders use a valid RFC822 date in this header.  Assuming you are not sorting spam, you can probably identify an alternative pattern for the correspondent(s) who do this; I will simply ignore that can of worms here. (I only bumped into this when handling spam, but it seemed to be fairly prevalent in email from Japan, IIRC.)

I see you don't care about the day of month, but I'm including that here as well just in case somebody else would find this useful.

```
# Poor man's associative array...  Remove leading zeros if desired
# (but then also change the MONTH regex below, as per comment there)
MONTHS='Jan 01
Feb 02
Mar 03
Apr 04
May 05
Jun 06
Jul 07
Aug 08
Sep 09
Oct 10
Nov 11
Dec 12'

:0
* ^Date:[   ]*[A-Z][a-z][a-z], \/[ 0-3][0-9] [A-Z][a-z][a-z] [12][0-9][0-9][0-9]
{
    RDATE=$MATCH
    :0
    * RDATE ?? ^ *\/[1-9][0-9]?
    { DAY=$MATCH }
    :0
    * RDATE ?? () \/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]
    { YEAR=$MATCH }
    :0
    * RDATE ?? () \/[A-Z][a-z][a-z]
    { MON=$MATCH }
    :0  # Adjust if you don't want leading zeros -- $MON \/[1-9][0-9]?
    * $ MONTHS ?? $MON \/[01][0-9]
    { MONTH=$MATCH }

    :0  # Assume TOPIC is set by caller, or somehow determined above
    $YEAR/$MONTH/$TOPIC
}
```

Just to recap the constructs used above, the `\/` special token causes whatever matches after it to be captured in `MATCH` (Procmail doesn't have proper back references) and `VAR ??` as the prefix of a condition causes the condition to be applied against the value of the variable `VAR` instead of against the message's headers.  Finally, `$` is required if you want the condition to contain the expanded value of a variable (normally, `$` just means a newline).  Oh, and as always, the whitespace in `[     ]*` is supposed to be a tab and a space.

The recipe above is mainly useful for parsing individual messages.  If you want to split a mailbox per date, I don't really see how you could avoid parsing each message separately and then filing each where it belongs.

If you really want to squeeze optimize, and have messages from a constrained period of time, I suppose you could enumerate regexes for each of the months you want to cover, something like

```
for month in 2014/11 2014/12 2015/01 2015/02 2015/03; do
    printf ':0\n* ^Date:[ \t]*[A-Z][a-z][a-z], [ 0-3][0-9] %s\n%s/$TOPIC\n' \
        "$(date -d "${month%/*}-${month#*/}-01" +'%b %Y')" "$month"
done >months.rc
```

but I'm not entirely convinced it will actually spare you any cycles (measure if you must! :-)

Comment: FWIW, the use of `date -d *date*` to obtain information for a date in the past is not supported on OSX.  Try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115740/19240) if you are on OSX / BSD.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this task I used a shell script and a procmailrc file.

The core of the shell script is just a way to split a huge mailbox and feed it to procmail with a tuned procmailrc file:

```
$ cat <<eof >splitter.sh
#!/bin/sh

orig_mailbox=$1

formail -s <${orig_mailbox} procmail ${HOME}/src/splitter_procmailrc
eof
```

And the procmailrc file is based on a single rule which will use `date` to extract the correct fields from the `Date:` header (which hopefully was a system generated one on a clean OS). `date` will also output the required fields `YYYY/MM` with the format `"+%Y/%m"`.

```
cat <<eof >${HOME}/src/splitter_procmailrc

MAILDIR=${HOME}/Mail/tmp
LOGFILE=${HOME}/Mail/tmp/procmail.log

:0 w
* ^Subject: TOPIC
* ^Date: \/.*$
|    (    ;\
          ORIG_MONTH_DIR=`date -j -f "%a, %d %b %Y" "${MATCH}" "+%Y/%m"` ;\
          [ -d ${ORIG_MONTH_DIR} ] || mkdir -p ${ORIG_MONTH_DIR} ;\
          cat >>${ORIG_MONTH_DIR}/TOPIC ;\
     )
:0 E
Error
eof
```

The second rule is here just in case I catch any error on the first one
so as to be able to sort the problem and tune the procmailrc file.